# What is the explanation of this java line?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. Could someone explain this line to me ?

```
Math.sqrt(6 * (1 until 10000).map(x => (1 / Math.pow(x.toDouble, 2))).sum)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like java to me.

Comment: It is [Scala](http://scala-lang.org/), not Java.

Comment: I don't think this is Java. I can understand it could be Java 8, because of the lambda expression. But `until` is still not a Java keyword (not even in Java 8).

Comment: Anyway, *verify the language* and *update the title/tags* as appropriate .. also expand on which part(s) of the syntax need explaining (if indeed desiring to learn Scala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no Java.

It looks more like Scala.

I think in Java it would look like this:

```
double y=0d;
for(int x=1;x< 10000; x++){
    y+=(1 / Math.pow(x,2);
}
y = 6*y;
Math.sqrt(y);
```

Comment: Ok this is Scala, my bad.
Thank you for rewriting the code for me, as I'm not familiar with Scala syntax. What interested me was the final value of this calculus, which turned out to be π :)

Answer (score 4):

It's called **syntax error**.

Your code is either not Java, or you didn't understand your assignment properly.

Answer (score 1):

The code is [Scala](http://scala-lang.org/), not Java.

---

In any case, the expression can be broken up as ..

```
val fn = (x: Int) => 1 / Math.pow(x.toDouble, 2)
val inner = (1 until 10000).map(fn).sum
```

.. which reads something like:

> For all integers in the range `[1, 10000)`, transform them via the function `f(x) -> 1/pow(x,2)` and sum the result.

Then whatever that result is, use it as input to the final sqrt.

```
Math.sqrt(6 * inner)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, this would be:

```
Math.sqrt(6 * IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10000)
                       .mapToDouble(x -> (1.0 / Math.pow((double)x, 2.0)))
                       .sum())
```